# Provide a PDF Functionality of default grid layout in universal windows-10 app for for Mobile

Tags: windows, xaml, pdf, win-universal-app

I want to generate a PDF File of my Invoice.Xaml Page layout in windows universal platform in windows -10 for mobile view.

I don't have any idea about it and I am on initial stage so i can't afford any paid api/DLL so please suggest me a better solution which has no cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the default print dialog and choose "Print to PDF" as your printer. Check out the MSDN docs about how to [print from your app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app) and the [GitHub sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing)

Comment: I got the point and  i know about  the "Print Functionality" but you didn't understand my query. I have a sales module(Invoice.xaml), In that module  i have two view  : 1)Desktop   2)Mobile.I done the print functionality in desktop view but in mobile view print will not use so here in mobile view i have to generate PDF file of my invoice.xaml page .So there the print dialog box how can i use?

Comment: The print functionality is available in Windows 10 Mobile also. You mean to say you can't use print in mobile view in your app because of your app based restrictions?

Comment: i understood but actually I want to generate a PDF so do you have any idea ? then  suggest me .

Comment: All other methods except "Print to PDF" use paid APIs.

Comment: Thank You so much for giving me best suggestion ever.